# Make SQL Server Agent retry failed script with Try/Catch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, error-handling, sql-server-agent

I have a script that has a try catch in it so that if it fails I can roll back the transaction. It runs on a job scheduled through SQL Server Agent. But when it fails SQL Server Agent does not see that it failed, I'm assuming because I catch the error. I want it to still retry the job even if I catch the error. I put in the RAISEERROR command in my catch part of the script to try and throw the error up to SQL Server Agent but it did not work. Any solutions?

Comment: What `RAISERROR` are you using?  The `severity` is relevant.  If it's too low it will be interpreted as informational only.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use [RAISERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) with severity 16?
This is "user defined error" and should be picked up by SQL Server agent

Did you set the job step to retry ([`Retry Interval` and `Retry Attempts`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190223.aspx))

Finally, is the error terminating (severity 20) such that the CATCH block isn't hit?